# While dismissing from one storyboard to other story board, its dismissing very lately in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am using two storyboard files due to two people working in same project, to avoid conflicts while merging storyboard files, we are using two storyboard files.

But, the issue is while navigating from 1 storyboard file to other its working fine, but while dismissing 1 storyboard to other, its taking time and very lately its dismissing.

For loading time from 1 to another storyboard

```
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ListViewController", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListViewController") as! ListViewController
    self.present(viewController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

I am using following code for dismissing storyboard

```
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Any suggestions to avoid this issue.

Comment: no this is not your all code, you are using something that is done first and take time, then you are using dismiss

Comment: updated, please check

Comment: please show us where do you use self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil), or just print time everywhere before dismiss to see what is taking this time

Comment: its taking around 5 seconds to dismiss

Comment: but show me what takes so long, is this dismiss the only code in your controller?

Comment: it is definitely NOT a dismiss alone that takes so long

Comment: I got issue, anyway thanks

Comment: Are you in the main Thread ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue, its happening due to previous viewcontroller doing calling webservice, so its takin few seconds time to call data, due to that, its taking time to dismissing.